# Convert bytes from a file to an integer c++

Tags: c++, parsing, byte

I am trying to parse a `.dat` file reading it byte by byte with this code.(the name of the file is in arv[1])

```
   std::ifstream is (arv[1], std::ifstream::binary);
      if (is) {

        is.seekg (0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg (0, is.beg);

        char * buffer = new char [length];

        is.read (buffer,length);

        if (is)
          std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
        else
          std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";
        is.close();
    }
```

Now all file is in the `buffer` variable. The file contains numbers represented in 32 bits, how can I  iterate over the buffer reading 4 bytes at a time and convert them to integer?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i< length; i+=4)

Comment: Yes, I know how to iterate over an array, the problem is how to convert 4 bytes read as char

Comment: You need to know whether the ints are stored as big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: they are stored as little-endian, but this is a problem that I will face later!

Comment: @Frog, you can't face the endian problem "later" -- you have to know the endiannes in order to convert them correctly to integer, because that determines how you will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all , you have a memory leak, you dynamically allocate character array but never delete[] them.
use `std::string` instead:

```
std::string buffer(length,0);
is.read (&buffer[0],length);
```

now, assuming you had written the integer correctly, and have read it correctly into buffer, you can use this character array as pointer to integer:

```
int myInt = *(int*)&buffer[0];
```

(do you understand why?)
  if you have more then one integer stored:

```
std::vector<int> integers;
for (int i=0;i<buffer.size();i+=sizeof(int)){
 integers.push_back(*(int*)&buffer[i]);
}
```

Comment: This assumes the host architecture and the file use the same endianness but is otherwise correct. You could also replace the C-style casts with C++ casts but I guess that's a little nitpicky :)

Comment: I find that it makes more sense to use a `vector` as a RAII buffer than a `string`. Prior to C++11, there was no guarantee that the string had contiguous storage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
char * buffer = new char [length];
is.read (buffer,length);
```

You can use:

```
int numIntegers = length/sizeof(int);
int* buffer = new int[numIntegers];
is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), numIntegers*sizeof(int));
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

I am not seeing any problems with the approach I suggested. Here's a sample program and the output I see using g++ 4.9.2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

void writeData(char const* filename, int n)
{
   std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios::binary);
   for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
   {
      int num = std::rand();
      out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), sizeof(int));
   }
}

void readData(char const* filename)
{
   std::ifstream is(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
   if (is)
   {
      is.seekg (0, is.end);
      int length = is.tellg();
      is.seekg (0, is.beg);

      int numIntegers = length/sizeof(int);
      int* buffer = new int [numIntegers];
      std::cout << "Number of integers: " << numIntegers << std::endl;

      is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), numIntegers*sizeof(int));

      if (is)
         std::cout << "all characters read successfully." << std::endl;
      else
         std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read" << std::endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < numIntegers; ++i )
      {
         std::cout << buffer[i] << std::endl;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   writeData("test.bin", 10);
   readData("test.bin");
}
```

Output

```
Number of integers: 10
all characters read successfully.
1481765933
1085377743
1270216262
1191391529
812669700
553475508
445349752
1344887256
730417256
1812158119
```

Comment: it does not work properly well, numINtegers is right(because I know how many numbers are stored in the file and it is correct), but if I print the integers are all zeroes